# Probabilistic Graphical Model variable correlation

Tags: correlation, spatial, graphical-model

I want to use PGM plate model to model gas prices in an area. The gas prices in the area are correlated and the correlation is measured by the physical distance of two gas stations: if two stations are physically close, the gas prices in the two stations are numerically close. How to use PGM plate model to represent this correlation (two gas stations' prices are not dependent)?

Comment: Don't you mean not independent?

Comment: I know this is a bit confusing. Let me give an example. If I have two samples $s_1$ and $s_2$ and they are the observations of the gas prices in station 1 and station 2 respectively and they are normal. I could use $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ to represent the true gas prices in the two stations. I also want to use the distance of two stations to adjust the true gas prices of two stations a little bit (the intuition is that if two stations are physically close, usually the gas prices should be close as well). How do I put the distance into the graph model to encode the 'distance influence'?